# App crashes when image url is not specified in CachedNetworkImage

Tags: image, flutter

I'm trying to use flutter_cached_network_image.
If there is an error in url or if there is no image in specified link (404) app just crashes.
There is errorWidget property in CachedNetworkImage and I think it should work in any case when there is an error in loading network image.
How can I achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of `cached_network_image 0.8.0`? I tried to reproduce your case, but with the latest version everything seems to work just fine: 404 http status code lunches the error widget builder.

Comment: Thank you it seems that app stopped crashing after updating to 0.8.0.   
I still get exceptions when debugging if the URL is  wrong.